# Bounty or new question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Suppose, I need a clarification on a question. Should I place a bounty on the question I need clarification on and ask the answerers to make their post more informative or should I post another question that asks to clarify the original post? In essence, it is mostly the same thing but what is your opinion? Does it really matter? While there be more duplicates due to this?

Thanks

Comment: I would say it depends on how different the question you would ask is from the original.

Comment: Similar question: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is better to place a bounty on your current question.  This way, the current answers will (ideally) be improved, rather than a new set of answers added, which gives the question more "archive value" (i.e. more readable to future interested users).